# How to add column to data.table with values from list based on regex

Tags: regex, r, list, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
    id      fShort
1   432-12  1245
2   3242-12 453543
3   324-32  45543
4   322-34  45343
5   2324-34 13543


DT <- data.table(
        id=c("432-12", "3242-12", "324-32", "322-34", "2324-34"), 
        fShort=c("1245", "453543", "45543", "45343", "13543"))
```

and the following list:

```
filenames <- list("3242-124342345.png", "432-124343.png", "135-13434.jpeg")
```

I would like to create a new column "fComplete" that includes the complete filename from the list. For this the values of column "id" need to be matched with the filename-list. If the filename starts with the "id" string, the complete filename should be returned. I use the following regex

```
t <- grep("432-12","432-124343.png",value=T)
```

that return the correct filename.

This is how the final table should look like:

```
    id      fShort      fComplete
1   432-12  1245    432-124343.png
2   3242-12 453543  3242-124342345.png
3   324-32  45543   NA
4   322-34  45343   NA
5   2324-34 13543   NA


DT2 <- data.table(
         id=c("432-12", "3242-12", "324-32", "322-34", "2324-34"), 
         fshort=c("1245", "453543", "45543", "45343", "13543"), 
         fComplete = c("432-124343.png", "3242-124342345.png", NA, NA, NA))
```

I tried using apply and data.table approaches but I always get warnings like

```
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What is a simple approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
DT[ , fComplete := lapply(id, function(x) {
  m <- grep(x, filenames, value = TRUE)
  if (!length(m)) NA else m})]


        id fShort          fComplete
1:  432-12   1245     432-124343.png
2: 3242-12 453543 3242-124342345.png
3:  324-32  45543                 NA
4:  322-34  45343                 NA
5: 2324-34  13543                 NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I messed up the naming of my columns but your solution still uses the correct variable ("id") for the comparision and works fine. I corrected my question text.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with similar functions, sometimes the regex functions return a list, so you have to consider that in the apply - I usually do an example manually
Also apply will not always in y experience on its own return something that always works into a data.frame,sometimes I had to use lap ply, and or unlist and data.frame to modify it

Here is an answer - I am not familiar with data.tables and I was having issues with the filenames being in a list, but with some transformations this works. I worked it out by seeing what apply was outputting and adding the [1] to get the piece I needed

```
DT <- data.frame(
  id=c("432-12", "3242-12", "324-32", "322-34", "2324-34"), 
  fShort=c("1245", "453543", "45543", "45343", "13543"))

filenames <- list("3242-124342345.png", "432-124343.png", "135-13434.jpeg")
filenames1 <- unlist(filenames)

x<-apply(DT[1],1,function(x) grep(x,filenames1)[1])
DT$fielname <- filenames1[x]
```